# OWA to standalone Outlook application

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-outlook-2010

Could you advise if there is a way to connect to my Outlook Web Access account and send/receive
mail from standalone Outlook 2010 application?

Answer (score 0):

Yes. If you are using Outlook Web Access, then its obviously an Exchange server account. All you need to do is follow the steps present in this [Microsoft URL](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/287532) based on your Outlook version. (2007/2010). Let me know if you have any issues while adding email account to Outlook.

Steps:
Here are the steps which I did: 
Note: If you are able to access an email account via Outlook Web Access, then it is definitely Exchange Server Account.

1. Start Outlook.
2. On the File menu, click Info, and then click Account Settings.
3. Select Account Settings from the drop-down list.
4. On the Email tab, click New, select Email Account, and then click Next.
5. To configure the new email account automatically, in the Add New E-mail Account dialog box under Auto Account Setup, follow these steps:
6. In the Your Name box, type your full name.
7. In the E-mail Address box, type your email address.
8. In the Password box, type the password.
9. In the Retype Password box, retype the password, and then click Next to begin the Auto Account Setup process.

Outlook will try to automatically configure your account settings and server settings. If your account is successfully configured, the Add New E-mail Account dialog box indicates that the account was created successfully. This dialog box also indicates the type of email server to which you are successfully connected.

Click Finish, and then click Close to complete the account setup.

If in between, Authentication popup appears then do enter the domain/userid and password to confirm the authentication process. This credentials are same to what you enter when you logon to the Outlook Web Access.

Comment: That MS Support link provides info on how to connect to a POP/IMAP remote account not an OWA service. This does not solve the OP's issue (which I also have).

Comment: Updated above reply